# restriction of functions of several variables

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \Bbb R ^n \to \Bbb R $  will be differentiable function satisfying the condition
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}  y_i \frac{ \partial f}{ \partial x_i } (y) \ge 0 $$ for every vector  $ y=(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$

Demonstrate that the function is bounded from below by $f(0)$

I don't any ideas.
Partial derivatives and differentiability have a few days.

Maybe we need a definition of the gradient, but still I could not take advantage of her.

Help me, please

Comment: $$f(y) - f(0) = \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt} f(t\cdot y)\,dt$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When beginning to prove things in multivariable calculus, it is important to recognise when you can reduce problems to one-dimensional ones (i.e. bring them within the scope of single variable calculus).

In this case, we can do this by defining the function:

$g: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\quad g(t)=f(yt)$

for an arbitrary fixed y.

Our aim is to show that $g(1)\geq g(0)$. Use the chain rule to differentiate $g$ and show this.